# POSIX Shell sh get currently executed line number

Tags: shell, sh, posix

How to get currently executed line number in POSIX shell script?
For example I have a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

echo "A"
echo "B"

echo "Script '$0' error at line no: <line-no>"
exit 1

echo "C"
```

and I would like get in place of `<line-no>` the current line of the script so the output is for eg:

Script 'script.sh' error at line no: 8

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$LINENO](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03):

> `LINENO`
>
> Set by the shell to a decimal number representing the current sequential line number (numbered starting with 1) within a script or function before it executes each command. If the user unsets or resets LINENO, the variable may lose its special meaning for the life of the shell. If the shell is not currently executing a script or function, the value of LINENO is unspecified. This volume of POSIX.1-2017 specifies the effects of the variable only for systems supporting the User Portability Utilities option.

Comment: I replaced `<line-no>` with `$LINENO` but got error: `./script.sh: 8: ./script.sh: LINENO: parameter not set`

Comment: Debian's dash is not POSIX compatible because they [disable LINENO](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582952) to work around broken package builds. Try it again in a POSIX shell.